# How exactly does the argument for linear coordinate transformations work in Einstein's Meaning of Relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

In *Meaning of Relativity* (German *Grundzüge der Relativitätstheorie*), Einstein starts out by showing why the coordinate transformations in Euclidean geometry must be linear.

He says that a space of reference is Euclidean and the co-ordinate system Cartesian if an arbitrary interval described by $\Delta x_1,\Delta x_2,\Delta x_3$ has squared length
$$s^2=\Delta x_1^2+\Delta x_2^2+\Delta x_3^2\quad(1)$$
for every orientation of the interval (I use the same equation numbers as in Einstein's text).

Then, he aims to find the coordinate transformation from one set of Cartesian co-ordinates $x_1,x_2,x_3$ to another set of co-ordinates $x_1',x_2',x_3'$.
For that, he considers a sphere made up of intervals in both coordinate systems, described by the equations
$$\sum\Delta x_{\nu}^2=\text{const.}\quad(2)$$
$$\sum\Delta x_{\nu}'^2=\text{const.}\quad(2a)$$
He taylors the $x_{\nu}'^2$ in terms of the $x_{\nu}^2$:
$$\Delta x_{\nu}'=\sum_{\alpha}\frac{dx_v'}{dx_{\alpha}}\Delta x_{\alpha}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha,\beta}\frac{d^2x_v'}{dx_{\alpha}dx_{\beta}}\Delta x_{\alpha}\Delta x_{\beta}+\dots\quad(\star)$$
Then, he says to "substitute" $(\star)$ in (2a)$^*$ and "compare with (1)" and that from there "we see that the $x_v'$ must be **linear functions** of the $x_v$".

Frankly, I don't understand why this is the case.
When substituting $(\star)$ in (2a), we get a lot of terms with derivatives.
In order to deduce that the transformation is linear, we must lose all of them except for the first ones, which must be constant.
I don't see how this can be deduced by the right side being constant and by "comparing" with (1).
I don't see what is there to compare and how (1) even differs from (2).

I found [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/443329/how-to-interpret-einsteins-development-of-euclidean-orthogonal-transformations) question that is still unanswered.
It also pertains to the translation error (see below), but mainly it is the same question that I have (and someone in the comments asks two years after it was posted if they found an answer).
I also found [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/443329/how-to-interpret-einsteins-development-of-euclidean-orthogonal-transformations), which goes a bit further because it involves Minkowski space-time, but it is certainly related.
I don't understand the answers to this question either, to be honest, but they seem quite involved.
In *Meaning of Relativity*, it sounds obvious, however, so I am wondering what I am missing.

Thank you!

$^*$ There is a translation error where the English version states the inverse, see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/443329/how-to-interpret-einsteins-development-of-euclidean-orthogonal-transformations) question.

Answer (score 1):

> In *Meaning of Relativity* (German *Grundzüge der Relativitätstheorie*)...

> For that, he considers a sphere made up of intervals in both coordinate systems, described by the equations
> $$\sum\Delta x_{\nu}^2=\text{const.}\quad(2)$$
> $$\sum\Delta x_{\nu}'^2=\text{const.}\quad(2a)$$
> He taylors [sic] the $x_{\nu}'^2$ in terms of the $x_{\nu}^2$:
> $$\Delta x_{\nu}'=\sum_{\alpha}\frac{dx_v'}{dx_{\alpha}}\Delta x_{\alpha}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha,\beta}\frac{d^2x_v'}{dx_{\alpha}dx_{\beta}}\Delta x_{\alpha}\Delta x_{\beta}+\dots\quad(\star)$$
> Then, he says to "substitute" $(\star)$ in (2a)$^*$ and "compare with (1)" and that from there "we see that the $x_v'$ must be **linear functions** of the $x_v$".

> Frankly, I don't understand why this is the case.
> When substituting $(\star)$ in (2a), we get a lot of terms with derivatives.

I will begin by noting that modern notation would use the $\partial$ symbol rather than the $d$ symbol for partial derivatives. But I will continue to use your notation.

OK, let's do what Einstein suggests.

Doing so yields:
$$
s^2 = \sum_\nu {\left( 
\sum_{\alpha}\frac{dx_v'}{dx_{\alpha}}\Delta x_{\alpha}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha,\beta}\frac{d^2x_v'}{dx_{\alpha}dx_{\beta}}\Delta x_{\alpha}\Delta x_{\beta}+\dots
\right)}^2
$$

The only term in the square that can contribute to give a second power of $\Delta x_\nu$ is the first term.

So we have:
$$
s^2 = \sum_\nu {\left( 
\sum_{\alpha}\frac{dx_v'}{dx_{\alpha}}\Delta x_{\alpha}\right)}^2 + O(\Delta x^3)
$$

The $O(\Delta x^3)$ term has to be zero, so we have to have:
$$
\frac{d}{dx_{\gamma}}\frac{dx_v'}{dx_{\alpha}} = 0
$$
for all $x_\gamma$.

Or, rather:
$$
\frac{dx_v'}{dx_{\alpha}} = \Lambda^{\alpha}_{\nu}\;,
$$
where the $\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\nu}$ are constants. These constant coefficients are the usual Lorentz transformation matrices.

Comment: Thank you. When having substituted $(\star)$ in (2a), when you set it equal to $s^2$, are you comparing coefficients? Otherwise, why does it hold that "The (Δ3) term has to be zero, so we have to have:"?

To be totally consistent with notation, I suppose $s$ should be $s'$ since it pertains to the $x_v'$ originally, now having been substituted. Then, because the spheres have different radii in different co-ordinate systems, you could set $s'=\lambda s$. Then I could see that by comparing coefficients, everybody is zero except for the first derivatives, their sums equal to $\lambda^2$.